# ¿Cómo realizo adecuadamente esta consulta? - Oracle

Tags: oracle

Buenas tardes, quisiera realizar la siguiente consulta: Código del tiquete, nombre, apellido, origen, destino, hora_inicio, hora_fin, pero origen y destino el nombre de la ciudad más no el código de la misma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

    create table aerolinea(
        cod_aerol number(6) not null,
        nom_aerol char(20) not null,
        constraint pk_aerolinea primary key(cod_aerol)
    );

    insert into aerolinea
        values('000001', 'Avianca');

    insert into aerolinea
        values('000002', 'Copa Airlines');

    insert into aerolinea
        values('000003', 'American Airlines');

    insert into aerolinea
        values('000004', 'Air France');


    create table ciudad(
        cod_ciudad number(4) not null,
        nom_ciudad char(20) not null,
        pais char(20) not null,
        constraint pk_ciudad primary key(cod_ciudad)
    );

    insert into ciudad
        values('0001', 'Cali', 'Colombia');

    insert into ciudad
        values('0002', 'Bogota', 'Colombia');

    insert into ciudad
        values('0003', 'Madrid', 'España');

    insert into ciudad
        values('0004', 'Paris', 'Francia');

    create table vuelo(
        cod_vuelo number(8) not null,
        capacidad number(3) not null,
        h_inicio date not null,
        h_fin date not null,
        origen number(4) not null,
        destino number(4) not null,
        escalas number(1) not null,
        cod_aerol number(6) not null,
        constraint pk_vuelo primary key(cod_vuelo),
        constraint fk_vuelo_ciudad_origen foreign key(origen) references ciudad(cod_ciudad),
        constraint fk_vuelo_ciudad_destino foreign key(destino)  references ciudad(cod_ciudad),
        constraint fk_vuelo_aerolinea foreign key(cod_aerol) references aerolinea(cod_aerol)
    );

    insert into vuelo
        values('00000001','90','13-06-2017 20:19:00','14-06-2017 06:10:00','0001','0004','2','000004');

    insert into vuelo
        values('00000002','85','14-06-2017 17:00:00','14-06-2017 19:00:00','0001','0002','1','000002');

    insert into vuelo
        values('00000003','74','15-06-2017 07:30:00','15-06-2017 20:25:00','0004','0001','2','000003');

    insert into vuelo
        values('00000004','69','16-06-2017 09:05:00','16-06-2017 20:51:00','0003','0001','2','000001');

    create table pasajero(
        cod_pasajero number(11) not null,
        nombre varchar(30) not null,
        apellido varchar(30) not null,
        edad number(3) not null,
        ciudad number(4) not null,
        telefono char(15) not null,
        direccion varchar(25) not null,
        constraint pk_pasajero primary key(cod_pasajero),
        constraint fk_pasajero_ciudad foreign key(ciudad) references ciudad(cod_ciudad)
    );

    insert into pasajero
        values('1144100513','Jairo Andrés', 'Valencia Valenzuela', '19', '0001','3012669651', 'Carrera 48 No. 42-24');

    insert into pasajero
        values('1142045221','Pedro José', 'Lovato Medrano', '38', '0002','3120421143', 'Av 6N No. 3N-27');

    insert into pasajero
        values('1143933323','Yuly Andrea', 'Zamudio Valencia', '24', '0001','3178952414', 'Calle 3 Oeste No. 16-77');

    insert into pasajero
        values('1143499521','Anyi Daniela', 'Lozano Solarte', '19', '0002','3178952414', 'Calle 8N No. 16N-77');

    create table tickets(
        cod_ticket number(8) not null,
        cod_vuelo number(8) not null,
        cod_pasajero number(11) not null,
        precio number(15) not null,
        constraint pk_tickets primary key(cod_ticket),
        constraint fk_tickets_vuelo foreign key(cod_vuelo) references vuelo(cod_vuelo),
        constraint fk_tickets_pasajero foreign key(cod_pasajero) references pasajero(cod_pasajero)
    );


    insert into tickets
        values('00000001', '00000001', '1144100513', '3600000');

    insert into tickets
        values('00000002', '00000002', '1142045221', '5700000');

    insert into tickets
        values('00000003', '00000003', '1143933323', '9300000');

    insert into tickets
        values('00000004', '00000004', '1143499521', '7200000');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que añadir dos nuevas `JOIN`s con la tabla ciudad, en una `JOIN` utilizarías el campo `origen` para la condición y en la otra el campo `destino`.

Para distinguir la tabla `ciudad` de cada una de las `JOIN`s deberás darles un alias.

Por ejemplo en este ejemplo les doy el alias `ciudad_origen` y `ciudad_destino`:

```
SELECT cod_ticket, nombre, apellido, ciudad_origen.nom_ciudad origen,
  ciudad_destino.nom_ciudad destino, h_inicio, h_fin
FROM tickets
INNER JOIN vuelo ON tickets.cod_vuelo = vuelo.cod_vuelo
INNER JOIN pasajero ON tickets.cod_pasajero = pasajero.cod_pasajero
INNER JOIN ciudad ciudad_origen ON vuelo.origen = ciudad_origen.cod_ciudad
INNER JOIN ciudad ciudad_destino ON vuelo.destino = ciudad_destino.cod_ciudad;
```

Comment: Exactamente el resultado que esperaba, pero me perdí un poco, ejemplo ciudad_origen.nom_ciudad en esa parte que haces, disculpa.

Comment: Le indico que coja el campo nom_ciudad pero de la tabla con alias ciudad_origen que es la tabla ciudad filtrada con el campo vuelo.origen. De esta forma obtienes el valor de nombre de la ciudad origen

Comment: Igual noté que en los dos últimos joins usaste vuelo.origen y por que no vuelo.destino ? en la última. Gracias

Comment: En ese caso, repetiría ambos casos, tendría que ser vuelo.destino

Comment: Efectivamente debería ser vuelo.destino. He editado la respuesta para corregirlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte amigo, es de mucha ayuda en mi práctica.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer un `JOIN` con la tabla `CIUDAD` para obtener los nombres del destino y el origen. En tu caso vas a necesitar un `JOIN` para cada uno de los campos.

```
SELECT COD_TICKET,
  NOMBRE,
  APELLIDO,
  ORI.NOM_CIUDAD ORIGEN,
  DES.NOM_CIUDAD DESTINO,
  H_INICIO,
  H_FIN
FROM TICKETS
    INNER JOIN VUELO
    ON TICKETS.COD_VUELO = VUELO.COD_VUELO
    INNER JOIN PASAJERO
    ON TICKETS.COD_PASAJERO = PASAJERO.COD_PASAJERO
    LEFT JOIN CIUDAD ORI
    ON VUELO.ORIGEN = ORI.COD_CIUDAD
    LEFT JOIN CIUDAD DES
    ON VUELO.DESTINO = DES.COD_CIUDAD;
```

Espero que esto te funcione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por tu aporte, es de gran ayuda.